# Issues with combining different (continuous and ordinal) plot types into one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am preparing a figure for a paper presenting data for 2 different experiments in one plot. For that reason I don't need a legend for every plot, so I try to combine them with ggdraw from cowplot.

My [code](https://pastebin.com/m2AbTm7t)
`should generate a reproducible example`
and gives this output:
[image]
It seems like the two figures get the same slot (A) and the legend gets slot (B). Typically, I would probably use facet wrap to plot them together (which should also guarantee that the scaling/legend is consistent across the two plots.), but that will probably not work in this case, as I am trying to add an additional figure type to C and D.

The problem is that this figure type is ordinal so I have used a somewhat “hacky” approach to plot it, giving me this figure looking essentially as I want it to:
[image]

I so far have not been able to extract to another element that ggdraw can use.

Ideally the final plot should roughly look like this (of course with different labels):
[image]

How would you go about plotting these different types together?

Thank you for taking time to read my question and I hope that you can help me. I now it is quite a mouth full, but I was not sure how I meaningfully could reduce it to smaller chunks.